# how to unmount EC2 ephemeral storage which is present in my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i am New to Amazon.i have one EC2 instance which i am using, contains 2 ephemeral storage's.When ever i create new AMI from this instance, i can see this 2 Storages are present. is there any way to unmount or remove from my EC2 instance? Can you please any ides with boto or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ephemeral storage is essentially *"free"* storage that comes with EC2. You do not have to pay any extra for it, nor does it take up any space for AMI.

You can forcefully unmount with:

```
sudo umount -d /dev/sdb
```

But, really, why bother.

Comment: Hi UZYN , thanks for reply...why i want to ummount is , i am getting confused in drives. i have d & E drive are Ephemeral memory. so, i f someone add any file, it will be deleted after Ec2 is stopped.

Comment: Hi UZYN,
Using boto we can unmount?